# how do I configure the code directories in karma for angular2?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I setup a new workspace following the [Angular2 5 minute QuickStart for TypeScript](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).
I ran **npm test**, and it worked.

Then I tried to rename the **app** directory to **other**.

But I cannot get this to work.
I tried modifying the **karma.conf.js** file:

```
var appBase   = 'other/'
```

but karma didn't run my tests.

Then I also modified **systemjs.config.js**:

```
var map = {  
    'app':                        'other'
```

and it still doesn't work.

Unfortunately, I find the related documentation very confusing,
as it usually doesn't clarify how to map a path from the browser to a path in the local file system.

I also don't understand where **app** refers to the a directory on the server, a path in the browser, or a property in a configuration.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To what does **/base/** refer?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve by replacing **app** with **other** but it generally is not a good practice.

> I also don't understand where app refers to the a directory on the server, a path in the browser, or a property in a configuration.

**app** is a directory under `angular2-quickstart` in your local machine where you write actual angular code (`components, services, directive, routers` ).

when you launch karma, it simple runs a local server which loads all of your dependencies/angularcode/tests specified in `files` array.
not sure what you might have missed (no error message posted) but the changes you made are not the only one needed to run the app. like :

```
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }, // <-- need to change it to 'other' as well
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
```

but it would suggest you to stick with name **app**.

Comment: Please explain why it is not good practice to use a name other than app. It seems I should be able to use any name, and any path.

Comment: you can name it whatever you like. but as per style guide by angular team it is good to name app for your main app folder. please look here https://johnpapa.net/angular-2-styles/ and https://angular.io/styleguide. furthermore you wont find any angular repo on github which have other name then `app`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I made the following changes:

**karma.conf.js**

```
var appBase   = 'other/'
```

**karma-test-shim.js**

```
function isBuiltFile(path) {
  var builtPath = '/base/other/';
```

**systemjs.config.js**:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'other', // 'dist',
```

Comment: The same issue on the quickstart: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/106